# How to insert data to database table from $_GET value on PHP

Tags: php, sql, get

Why I can't insert into 1 field to my database table?

I loop the data of my other table to display each data and put the result to `href` tag so it clickable and concatenate with it's id so it will put the id result after the link like this:

```
<a href="scheduling.php?CID=<?php echo $rows['docID']; ?>">
```

Here is how I loop my data using php on page1:

```
<?php
$sel = "SELECT * FROM doctors ORDER BY docID";
$result = $conn->query($sel);
if($result->num_rows>0)
{
    while($rows = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        ?>
        <a href="scheduling.php?CID=<?php echo $rows['docID']; ?>">
        <div class="doc_item" style="width:310px; border:4px solid #009973;display:inline-block; margin-top:40px; margin-right:20px;">
            <img src="images/ft-img.png" style="width: 300px;">
            <div class="item-lvl" style="width: 100%; background:#009973; color:#fff; height:70px; padding-top:10px;">
                <h4 style="font-size:20px; font-weight:bold;">Dr. <?php echo $rows['docFname']; ?></h4>
                <span><?php echo $rows['docType']; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 100%; background:#00664d;padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                <h3 style="color:#fff;">Make a Schedule!</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Then I want to add the value of CID to my database table using this code on page 2:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {
        $cusID = $customerID;
        $docID = $_GET['CID'];
        $checkupType = $_POST['checkupType'];
        $schedTime = $_POST['schedTime'];
        $contact = $_POST['contact'];

        $ins = "INSERT INTO schedule 
                        (customerID, docID, checkupType, schedTime, contact) 
                  VALUE ('$cusID','$docID','$checkupType','$schedTime','$contact')";
        if($conn->query($ins)===TRUE) {
            header('location:success_sched.php');
        }else{
            echo "SQL Query: " . $ins . "->Error: " . $conn->error;
        }
    }
```

Now, this code insert data to my database table except $docID which is the value is $_GET['CID'];
docID column is intiger.
please correct my code, this is my school project.

Form code on page 2:

```html
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                            <div class="sign-u">
                                <div class="sign-up1">
                                    <h4>Form of Checkup* :</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sign-up2">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" value="Virtual" name="checkupType" required>
                                        Virtual Checkup
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" value="Facetoface" name="checkupType" required>
                                        Face to Face Checkup
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <p style="color:gray;">*Take note that virtual checkup will require a you stable internet for better communication.</p>
                            
                            <div class="sign-u">
                                <div class="sign-up1">
                                    <h4>Date and Time* :</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sign-up2">
                                        <input type="date" name="schedTime" id="date" required> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <p style="color:gray;">*Please provide Skype id as a contact information if <span style="color:#ff5c33">Virtual Checkup</span> is your choice.</p>
                            <div class="sign-u">
                                <div class="sign-up1">
                                    <h4>Contact Information :</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="sign-up2">
                                    
                                        <input type="text" name="contact">
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sub_home" style="text-align: right;">
                                
                                    <input style="background: #339966;" type="submit" name="btn-submit" value="Submit">
                                
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input. It's no all about security. If any of those values contains some specific characters, for example a single quote `'`, your query would break.

Comment: When you click the anchor link you will get passed `$_GET['CID'];` but you will not get anything in the `$_POST`. Specifically this IF statement  `if (isset($_POST['btn-submit'])) {`will not get entered

Comment: Did you getting docID value in php file? First print docID before query and check it.

Comment: Where's the form you're submitting? That's the one that needs the `CID` in the URL (or better yet, add it as a hidden input in the form).

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. As you showed yourself in your own screenshot, the only value being passed to the server in your request is the `CID` value. So where do you suppose `btn-submit` and all the others are going to come from? You've submitted a GET request with one value. So that's what you'll see. If you want to look for values using $_POST then you need to ensure the browser submits a POST request (e.g. by submitting a suitable-configured form), not a GET. Clicking on a link always sends a GET.

Comment: thanks you for teaching my, but for this project it doesn't concern me because its school project only, all I want now is to finish this f**king project so I can see my family on new year.

Comment: Please don't swear (even with **s). Actually you _should_ be concerned with learning this about injection attacks, because it will help you write better code. And it can protect against other unexpected syntax errors as well (e.g. right now your code would fail if anyone included a simple `'` in any of the inputs). And I wouldn't consider a project "finished" if it contained such obvious problems.

Comment: It's unclear though, how, or if, you are submitting data to the last piece of code you wrote. Your question is not very coherent. Don't forget, we cannot implicitly understand what you are doing. You need to show us, step by step. You say "this code insert data"...but it's not clear how that happens, from what you've shown us.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You're going to need to show us the html of page 2 so we understand how you are submitting the data.

Comment: @ADyson do I have to show all of the code for my page 2 or the form code only?

Comment: It's likely that the form is sufficient. Start with that.

Comment: @ADyson I edited again my question, I added the form code on last part.

Comment: @VishalPavasiya I tried it and it work fine when when I print it to check, but if I want it to insert to my database field it always give 0 value to my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand that when you submit a form, that is a new request to the server. It has a new URL. Your page 2 form submits to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` - which is the current URL but *without the querystring variables*. Therefore your GET parameter is not passed in the form submit. (If you use the "View Source" feature of your browser to examine the "action" attribute of the form after it's rendered, you'll see exactly what URL it makes the request to when submitting. You can also see the same thing by looking at your browser's Network tool, or your webserver's access logs.)

There are a couple of ways around that, but I'd suggest adding the value as a hidden field in the form, and populating it with the value of the GET parameter during the previous request.

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET["CID]; ?>" name="CID">
```

and then in the PHP, retrieve it via $_POST like all the other variables:

```
$docID = $_POST['CID'];
```

---

Finally, please ensure you update your code to use prepared statements and parameters, as recommended in the comments, so that you are protected against both SQL injection attacks and unexpected syntax errors. You can get more info and examples [here](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli)